# Bump maps in paint mode appear very pixelated

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Tried searching the problem with no success: When painting bump maps in paint mode the result appear very coarse and pixelated. What puzzels me is that going op in (bump)image size worsens the problem.

Also tried swapping "linear" with "cubic" with no essential result.

Any suggestions? Is there something to adjust with the brush itself and if: Where?

Kind regards,
Raaskot

[image]

Comment: You need a 32-Bit Float PNG image, but if you convert your current 8-Bit to 32-Bit it won't work, but you can use the original picture, convert it, blur it

Comment: Yes, you nailed it;) I Forgot to select 32 bit when adding texture paint slot!

Comment: it took me time to understand the thing, because if you simply convert a bad picture it won't work  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need a *32-Bit Float* PNG image. If you convert your current *8-Bit* to *32-Bit* it won't work though, because it will still keep the bad pixelling, but you can use the original picture, convert it, blur it.

Answer (score 0):

With kind help from @moonboots:
Thanks!
[image]